# Netbeans no agrega las librerías al hacer build

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp, jar, mysqlconnector.jar

Buenas estoy usando netbeans para desarrollar una pequeña aplicación. La misma usa el conector de mysql para conectarse a una base de datos en phpmyadmin(XAMPP).

Todo el tema de la conexión funciona genial y el programa ejecuta perfectamente desde netbeans.

Cuando le doy a clean and build y se genera el .jar, el programa no funciona porque las librerías no se importan a la carpeta dist. (Las librerías/jar que uso son el driver de mysql-conector)

Cómo puedo hacer en Netbeans que se importen las librerías necesarias al proyecto.

Comment: Aclara tus conceptos... la base de datos no está en "phpmyadmin". En todo caso, bienvenido a SOe, pero revisa [faq] y [ask]. Indica qué código usas, qué mensajes de error te salen, etc. No podemos adivinar qué es lo que hace mal tu programa con la información que das.

Comment: En propiedades del proyecto en la opción *Build > Packaging* está la opción *Copy Dependent Libraries*.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás conectado a una red local
Entonces tienes que cambiar tu conexión por la ip de tu computadora (también la ip tiene que ser estática y no dinámica)
Y el .jar tendrias que volverlo .exe pero si te lo abre en .jar entonces solo prueba
Creo que tu error esta en la conexión a base de datos otra cosa es que en la carpeta que se crea cuando haces el .jar tiene que tener una sub-carpeta que contenga las librerías que utilizaste y la de la conexión